# Error handling for cancelled request

Tags: ios, swift, exception, alamofire, nserror

I use `Alamofire` to send a download request. I am handling `Success` and `Failure` cases as shown below.

```
Alamofire.request {
     case Success:
          // Update UI
     case Failure:
          // Show Alert message (error!.localizedDescription)
}
```

Everything is perfectly fine.

When I go back, in `viewWillDisappear`, I cancel any ongoing request. The issue is, canceling the request throws the error message and that triggers the alert when I am not on that screen.

To my knowledge, I can take two actions.

1. Check the condition if the error is created due to request cancel
2. Check if the `viewController` is alive
3. Also I can set a `Bool` variable in `viewWillDisappear`, which is a simple solution

How to handle the situation?

Also how to check point 1 & 2?

Comment: what is the real issue ? the user can't see the alert, or, the application crashes trying to show the alert ?

Comment: Basically I do not want to show the alert if the request is cancelled.

Comment: how can you show the alert if the view did disappear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to get the reason why it has failed, you should go with that, so: `Check the condition if the error is created due to request cancel`.

Option 2 is fragile, because you are relying on the `UIViewController`'s life cycle. Option 3 will only make your logic more cumbersome, via a new flag. Keep it simple

Comment: How do I check if the error is due to request cancel?

Comment: @iOS `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Saved my day!

Answer (score 16):

This is a more generic approach which works for any device language:

**Swift 4**

```
if (response.error as NSError?)?.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
   // Do Your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE: Use `aumanets` answer for failsafe check**

For the ppl who are wondering how to use the option 1

you can check the request cancelled error to find if the request is cancelled

```
let errorDict = (error as NSError).userInfo;
if let errorString = errorDict["NSLocalizedDescription"] as? String, errorString == "cancelled" {
    // Request is cancelled.
}
```

This answer is derived from @peres's answer.

Comment: This will not work if the device has different language than English

Answer (score 1):

Should be now:

```
var isCancelError: Bool {
    guard let afError = self as? AFError else { return false }
    return afError.isExplicitlyCancelledError
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by this genric approach

```
if let errorCode = (error.underlyingError as NSError?)?.code, errorCode == NSURLErrorCancelled { // for cancelled
```